# How do I delete a program header from an ELF binary

Tags: elf

I want to write a utility to remove a program header from an ELF binary.  For example, when I run readelf -l /my/elf I get a listing of all the program headers: PHDR INTERP ... GNU_STACK GNU_RELRO.  When I run my utility, I would like to get all the same program headers back in the same order, minus the one I deleted.  Is there any easier way to do this than recreated the entire ELF from scratch, skipping the unwanted header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any easier way to do this than recreated the entire ELF from scratch

Sure: program headers form a fixed-record table at an offset given by `ehdr.e_phoff`, containing `.e_phnum` entries of `.e_phentsize` bytes.

To delete one entry, simply copy the rest of entries over it, and decrement `.e_phnum`. That's all there is to it.

Beware: deleting some entries will likely cause the dynamic loader to crash. `GNU_STACK` is about the only header that can be deleted without too much harm (that I can think of).

Update:

Yes, setting `.p_type` to `PT_NULL` is another (and simpler) approach. But such entries are generally not expected to be present, and you may find some systems where `PT_NULL` will trigger an assertion in the loader (or in some other program).

Finally, adding a new `Phdr` might be tricky. Usually there is no space to expand the table (as it is immediately followed by some other data, e.g. `.text`). You can relocate the table to the end of the file, and set `.e_phoff` and `.e_phnum` to correspond to the new table, but many programs expect the entire `Phdr` table to be loaded and available at runtime, and that is not easy to arrange, as the new location at the end of the file will not be "covered" by any `PT_LOAD` segment.

Comment: Actually, the technique I decided on was to convert the one I deleted to PT_NULL.  But I'll try your technique too, sounds reasonable.  BTW, what about the converse?  Adding one?

Comment: Regarding adding one, it should be possible to insert a whole page (4k) of padding just after the end of the last old Phdr, then adjust the PT_LOAD entries to ensure that (1) the Phdr table is still mapped into memory, and (2) all existing PT_LOAD mappings still get the same virtual addresses they were intended to have.

Answer (score -1):

The GNU Binary File Descriptor library (libbfd) may be helpful.